# Hadoop issue with Sqoop installation

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have Hadoop(pseudo distributed mode), Hive, sqoop and mysql installed in my local machine.

But when I am trying to run sqoop Its giving me the following error

```
Error: /usr/lib/hadoop does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation.
```

Then I set the sqoop-env-template.sh file with all the information. Beneath is the snapshot of the sqoop-env-template.sh file.

[image]

Even after providing the hadoop hive path I face the same error.

I've installed 
hadoop in /home/hduser/hadoop     version 1.0.3

hive in /home/hduser/hive         version 0.11.0

sqoop in /home/hduser/sqoop       version 1.4.4

and mysql connector jar           java-5.1.29

Could anybody please throw some light on what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqoop-env-template.sh` is a **template**, meaning it doesn't by itself get sourced by the configurator.  If you want it to have a custom conf and load it, make a copy as `$SQOOP_HOME/conf/sqoop-env.sh`.

Note:  here is the relevant excerpt from [`bin/configure-sqoop` for version 1.4.4:](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/branch-1.4.4/bin/configure-sqoop)

```
SQOOP_CONF_DIR=${SQOOP_CONF_DIR:-${SQOOP_HOME}/conf}

if [ -f "${SQOOP_CONF_DIR}/sqoop-env.sh" ]; then
  . "${SQOOP_CONF_DIR}/sqoop-env.sh"
fi
```